# Contour Integral $\oint\limits_{C}\mathrm{d}z \,\sqrt{\frac{z-a}{z-b}}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

$C$ is any closed curve encompassing the whole branch cut.
The approach to this problem would involve using the residue theorem:

1) We first want to find the residues at infinity so we change the form to where we are able to perform a series expansion.

2) Obtain the coefficients of $\frac{1}{z}$.

3) Plug the residues back into the formula: $\oint\limits_{C}\mathrm{d}z \, f(z)=2\pi i \, \mathrm{Res}(f,\infty)$

So for the integral: $\oint\limits_{C}\mathrm{d}z \,\sqrt{\frac{z-a}{z-b}}$

I would like some help in obtaining the form which allows for an expansion. If this approach is bad for this integral, then please inform me of a better solution.

A similar problem has been posted before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2288715/integral-int-z-r-sqrtz-az-bdz-a-neq-b-rmaxa-b-z-in-c), for which $\oint\limits_{C}\mathrm{d}z \,\sqrt{(z-a)(z-b)} = \dfrac{\pi i}{4}(a-b)^2$. I am just referencing this because the problem is so similar as with our approach utilizing residues at infinity.

Comment: You did not tell us what $C$ is.  In particular are $a,b$ inside, outside, on that contour?

Comment: $C$ is just any closed curve encompassing the whole branch cut.

Comment: Of course that must be included in the question, not just mentioned in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More complete version of Pedrpan's answer...  As $z \to \infty$, we have
$$
\frac{z-a}{z-b} = \frac{1-a/z}{1-b/z} = 
\left(1-\frac{a}{z}\right)\left(1+\frac{b}{z}+O(z^{-2})\right)
= 1 +\frac{b-a}{z}+O(z^{-2})
$$
then one branch of the square root is analytic near $z=\infty$ and
$$
\left(\frac{z-a}{z-b}\right)^{1/2} = 1 +\frac{b-a}{2z}+O(z^{-2})
$$
We chose the branch of the square root so that the integrand $ \to 1$ at $z=\infty$.

The residue at $z=\infty$ is $\frac{b-a}{2}$ so the integral is
$$
2\pi i \frac{b-a}{2} = i\pi(b-a) .
$$

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on the other solution. Someone commented before that you could not use Cauchy's integral theorem because of analytic continuation problems. The comment is deleted now, but it would be really helpful for me if you could explain why there are no issues with analytic continuation, contrary to that person's claims.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $$\sqrt{\frac{z-a}{z-b}} = 1 + \frac{b-a}{2}\frac{1}{z} + O\bigg(\frac{1}{z^2}\bigg)$$ therefore using Cauchy's integral formula we have that $$\oint \sqrt{\frac{z-a}{z-b}}dz = 2 \pi i  \frac{b-a}{2} = (b-a)\pi i .$$

Comment: Thanks for answering! Just to clarify, what is the point you are expanding about and what are you using as $x$ for your first step.

Comment: Sorry about that. I changed the $x$'s to $z$'s. Hope that clarifies things.